# Seaborn ValueError: 'vertices' must be a 2D list or array with shape Nx2

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to do a very simple `seaborn.scatterplot`

My data is as per below:

```py
data.head()

date       adj_close    trade_type
2018-03-26    172.770    sell
2018-03-23    164.940    buy
2018-03-22    168.845    sell
2018-03-21    171.270    hold
2018-03-20    175.240    hold
```

**For this question, say my `plot_data` is:**

```py
plot_data = pd.DataFrame({"date" : pd.date_range(start='21/03/2018', periods=5), 
"adj_close" : [172.0, 165.0, 169.0, 171.3, 175.24], 
"trade_type" : ["sell", "buy", "sell", "hold", "hold"]})
```

When I try plot the data using `seaborn` I get the below error:

```py
import seaborn as sns
sns.scatterplot(x="date", y="adj_close", style="trade_type",
                data=plot_data)
```

> ValueError: 'vertices' must be a 2D list or array with shape Nx2

What's strange is if I **remove the `style`** parameter in the `scatterplot` it works 'perfectly':

```py
sns.scatterplot(x="date", y="adj_close",
                data=plot_data)
```

[image]

**Package & Sys Versions:**

- `seaborn` == 0.9.0
- `python` == 3.6.8 (anacondas)
- `matplotlib` == 2.0.2

*Additionally I am running this in ipython (version == 5.3.0)*

---

Any ideas ??

---

*++data types*

```py
data.dtypes
date          datetime64[ns]
adj_close            float64
trade_type            object
dtype: object
```

Comment: Nope: `np.sum(plot_data.trade_type.isnull())` returns 0

Comment: Show is the dtypes for plot_data? Is it possible that one of your columns has array data in it somewhere below head()?

Comment: Right. So when I run your code using only the data in your head(), it works fine. Something lower down must be affecting dimensionality?

Comment: Can you make this reproducible? Eg. with the `tips` dataset it works just fine.

Comment: I added a sample df which still returns the error when I try plot it

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error using your example dataframe using seaborn 0.9.0, python 3.7.0, matplotlib 3.1.0. I'd start by updating matplotlib. And double-check that your example (without any leftover interpreter history) reproduces the issue.

Comment: Ah it's the `matplotlib` version! I upgraded to `matplotlib 3.1.0` and it worked perfectly... Weird as I pip installed `seaborn` after  `matplotlib` and didn't update it